# Flutter firebase has different app name than the project

Tags: firebase, google-signin

I am setting up Google authentication (google sign in).

I added my debug SHA1 to the firebase settings.

Unfortunately, I get the exception `com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10:`

I noticed that the package name in Firebase is `com.example.xxx` whilst in the app is `com.xxx.xxx` and by the way, when I download the `google-services.json`, I have to change to match com.xxx.xxx in order to compile and run.

So the question is: do you think that the package name mismatch is the source of the issue? And how can I change it in the Firebase settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is definitively the problem.

So what to do is simply add a new app in Firebase and provide the right bundle name this time.

This isn't harmful to have multiple app of the same platform, so no problem.

Once the app is created, just download the google service file and replace the former you had in your project.

Once done, just rebuild the project and everything goes fine.

When yo witnessed that everything is ok, simply remove the former app from your Firebase dashboard as it is useless now.